# Why does my AJAX request depend on the file extension of the resource?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

In the following example, 'xxx.xml' is a valid XML file and 'xxx.txt' is a copy of it (but with the extension changed).

Why can't I use the files interchangeably in my AJAX request?

```
function test(url, handleT){
    dojo.xhrGet({
        url: url,
        handleAs: handleT,
        load: function(data, ioArgs) {
            console.log('data=',data);
        }
    });
}

test('xxx.xml', 'xml');  //Works OK
test('xxx.txt', 'text'); //Works OK
test('xxx.xml', 'text'); //Works OK

test('xxx.txt', 'xml');  //data === null ?!
```

Wasn't the `handleAs` parameter supposed to do these conversions for me already?

Is this something general or does it only occurs with Dojo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was Fiferox's fault all along:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#responseXML

(Didn't test how this works in IE yet)

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever extension you want if you write the following in a .htaccess located in the directory containing your files:

```
ForceType text/xml
```

Answer (score 0):

The webserver will serve different content-types for the extensions. Stick to .xml, or change it at the webserver.

EDIT

A bit more specific: Since XML is also text, it can be "downgraded" to text - every XML-document is also a text-document. Not every text-document is an XML-document, so you cannot "upgrade" it to XML.

Your webserver likely serves the .txt as "plain/text" - and that ain't XML.